# Fragment lifecycle. When would reference to a fragment become invalid?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If my Fragment implements an interface and another class, say the activity holds a reference to the fragment.

```
  IFragmentInterface myFragmentReference;
```

At what point in the fragments lifecycle is it no longer available?  And can this be detected by checking if the myFragmentReference is null?  (I am aware there is a FragmentManager class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure when the reference becomes invalid, but looking at the Android developer page on Fragments (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) it would appear to be in onDetach.

You can't detect this by checking if myFragmentReference is null, because the reference isn't null... it's just pointing to a Fragment that no longer exists.

The best way to handle this is to use something like the following whenever you need to do something with the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
IFragmentInterface myFragmentReference = (IFragmentInterface) fm.findFragmentByTag(getTag());
```

You'll need to set a tag when adding the fragment to use findFragmentByTag().

Comment: Is there anyway for the fragment object to know(guaranteed) that it is invalid? Is there some status field or something like that.  The reason is I'm asking for some async data and then invoking the callback on the Fragment. At this moment the fragment might be invalid so I need to for the fragment to only update say its TextView if its still a valid fragment.

Comment: I don't think you can access that information directly. You could either use a callback interface in onDestroy() to tell your host activity that the Fragment is being destroyed or you could wrap your update method in a try-catch, since if the Fragment no longer exists you'll just get an Exception

Comment: what type of exception would you get if you were say finding and updating a say a TextView on an invalid fragment?

Comment: I believe you would get an IllegalStateException. I haven't attempted to do a try-catch on this kind of thing before so I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

The `Fragment` itself is not usable as a `Fragment` anymore after `onDestroy()` is called. Your reference stays valid as long as you keep it. You can access all the methods from your interface, but you can just not use it as a `Fragment` anymore.

Comment: Ok. Can the fragment itself detect that it is no longer valid? I suppose I could provide a flag in onDestroy() ...  Is OnDestroy guaranteed to be called or is there some way a fragment object can get its status

Comment: I'm not sure if it is guaranteed that `onDestroy()` is called. It should usually i think. In the `Fragment` itself is't not so easy to figure out the current state. i at least have not yet figured out a reliable way to know if the `Fragment` is really showing or not. You can try one of the `Fragment.isXXX()` methods, but for me, they are not working reliable.